# Box plot using data series from a single row

Tags: excel, vba, boxplot

I want to generate box plots for all rows of a table.
[image: Example of the table]

I get something like this:
[image: Box plot result]

It only shows the value of the first column of the row.

If I use the same code on a column it works.

How do I process row data as a series?

```vb
Sub CreateWhiskerBox()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim cht As Shape
    Dim o_data As Range
    Dim n_data As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim mid_col As Integer
    Dim offset As Integer
    Dim c_min As Double
    Dim c_max As Double
    Dim scn_b As Series
 
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    last_col = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 3
    mid_col = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Find("o.std.dev", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart).Column
    offset = mid_col - 2
    
    For i = 1 To tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        Set o_data = tbl.ListRows(i).Range.Columns(2).Resize(, offset)
        Set n_data = tbl.ListRows(i).Range.Columns(mid_col + 2).Resize(, offset)
        
        'Set cht = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=500, Top:=GetChartTop(i), Height:=500) '375,225
        'cht.Chart.ChartType = xlBoxwhisker 'fails xlBoxwhisker not recognized
        
        Set cht = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlBoxwhisker, Left:=100, Width:=500, Top:=GetChartTop(i), Height:=500)
        cht.Chart.HasTitle = True
        cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = tbl.ListRows(i).Range.Cells(1, 1).Value ' Assuming Test Name is in the first column
        'cht.Chart.SetSourceData comb_data, PlotBy:=xlRows 'this method fails with ws.Shapes.AddChart2 declaration of cht.
        
        cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "New"
        cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = n_data
        
        Debug.Print i
    Next i
End Sub
```

*GetChartTop* basically gives a new Top value for each new chart.

I tried `.Add` to manually add a series and indicate the source, but it does not recognize parameters like `Rowcol` or `PlotBy`.